# How to get html data in an array form or xml form?

Tags: php, html, xml, web-scraping

I want to get my html data in an array form or xml format so that it can be easily saved in database. here is my work so far:

```
$url = "http://www.example.com/";

    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
    if($html = curl_exec($ch)){

        // parse the html into a DOMDocument
        $dom = new DOMDocument();

        $dom->recover = true;
        $dom->strictErrorChecking = false;

        @$dom->loadHTML($html);

        $hrefs = $dom->getElementsByTagName('div');


        curl_close($ch);


    }else{
        echo "The website could not be reached.";
    }
```

what should i do to get html in an array form or xml format. the html coming is like this:

```
<div>
 <ul>
   <li>Product Name</li>
   <li>Category</li>
   <li>Subcategory</li>
   <li>Product Price</li>
   <li>Product Company</li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of your previous question: [How to add scraped website data in database?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18997932/how-to-add-scraped-website-data-in-database). Please take care not to re-ask the same question more than once.

Answer (score 1):

For XML output just do like below:

```
function download_page($path){
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$path);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 15);
$retValue = curl_exec($ch);          
curl_close($ch);
return $retValue;
}

$sXML = download_page('http://example.com');
$oXML = new SimpleXMLElement($sXML);

foreach($oXML->entry as $oEntry){
    header('Content-type: application/xml')
    echo $oEntry->title . "\n";
}
```

Comment: But it gives me this error: 
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'String could not be parsed as XML' in D:\wampserver\www\test1.php:17 Stack trace: #0 D:\wampserver\www\test1.php(17): SimpleXMLElement->__construct('<!DOCTYPE html ...') #1 {main} thrown in D:\wampserver\www\test1.php on line 17