# crawl specific website data

Tags: php, web-crawler

There is a website [Jeeran](http://jeeran.com) it's listings website contain places and photos of the places 
what im looking to crawl is the places and there category like full crawl of it 
places - photos - categories and every thing in it 
Just the data

How is That Possible using PHP ?

Comment: The website doesn't provide any kind of api or rss

Comment: Use cURL to fetch the website content, use a DOM parser to extract the specific pieces.

Comment: Please, Any Tutorial to do that ?

Comment: I recently added [a substantial answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18998500/472495) on crawling generally, perhaps it might be useful.