# Screen scraping with Python/Scrapy/Urllib2 seems to be blocked

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, urllib2

To help me learn Python, I decided to screen scrape the football commentaries from the ESPNFC website from the 'live' page (such as [here](http://espnfc.com/uk/en/gamecast/367347/gamecast.html?soccernet=true&cc=5739)).

It was working up until a day ago but having finally sorted some things out, I went to test it and the only piece of commentary I got back was [u'Commentary Not Available'].

Does anyone have any idea how they are doing this, and any easy and quick ways around? I am using Scrapy/Xpath and Urllib2.

Edit//

```
for game_id in processQueue:
    data_text = getInformation(game_id)
    clean_events_dict = getEvents(data_text)
    break
```

Doesn't work the same as

```
i = getInformation(369186)
j = getEvents(i)
```

In the first sample, processQueue is a list with game_ids in.  The first one of these is given to the script to start scraping.  This is broken out of before it has a chance to move on to another game_id

In the second sample I use a single game id.

The first one fails and the second one works and I have absolutely no idea why.  Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure the values as passed to the first iteration of the first sample are the same as the values passed in the second sample? Check the types are the same too, and that you haven't confused integers/strings.

Comment: I am overjoyed, you are right.  I can't believe I was this much of an idiot to not check the url I was attempting to go to.  It wasn't a string, it was actually a massive list in the middle of the url.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: I am actually not sure that is the problem now I look again.  I think that might have been another problem I have created while trying to fix this.

Comment: I am even dumber than I realised, the first game it tries to scrape is a game that isn't being played until next month.  Words fail me.  Sorry.  Thanks.

Comment: No worries, fixing it is the important thing. Don't forget to accept my answer, if it helped - this also removes the question from "unanswered" lists.

Answer (score 0):

There's a few things you can try, assuming you can still access the data from your browser. Bear in mind, however, that web site operators generally are within their rights to block you; this is why projects that rely on the scraping of a single site are a risky proposition. Here they are:

- Delay a few seconds between each scrape
- Delay a random number of seconds between each scrape
- Accept cookies during your scraping session
- Run JavaScript during your session (not possible with Scrapy as far as I know)
- Share the scraping load between several IP ranges

There are other strategies which, I generally argue, are less ethical:

- Modify your User Agent string to make your scraper look like a browser

I [suggest in this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18998500/472495) that scrapers should be set up to obey robots.txt. However, if you program your scraper to be well-behaved, site operators will have fewer reasons to go to the trouble of blocking you. The most frequent errors I see in this Stack Overflow tag are simply that scrapers are being run far too fast, and they are accidentally causing a (minor) denial of service. So, try slowing down your scrapes first, and see if that helps.

Comment: My first guess would be to switch an IP, then change user agent.